# Visual Studio not showing committed files in Solution Explorer

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have committed files in Visual Studio and pushed them to a repo on Github. Now i pulled the repo but the committed files do not show up in Solution Explorer but i can see the history of the commits in the Team Explorer window. I can browse the files but i have no idea why they are not part of the solution[image]. I can open the file from history but it opens from some temporary location. I tried to revert to the last commit but still nothing shows up.

Comment: When you say "pulled" do you perhaps mean "fetch"? `git fetch` updates your local repo to the remote's changes whereas `git pull` updates your local branch to that of the remote.

Comment: Your .csproj need's to be committed as well, case your file are commited but the solution does not load the files.

Comment: @bcmcfc yes i meant pull. I tried the pull from the command line and also using the Github Desktop client. The files were synced to the local filesystem but apparently they didn't show up on the solution explorer. I fixed it by just re-adding the files from the filesystem and everything just worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the files on the branch (remote, local), go on that branch (if is local the files should be visible in solution explorer), if is remote branch, pull to the latest, re include those files in projects via solution explorer (click show all files, add one by one right click -> add in project).

Edit gitignore file, recommended visual studio Git ignore https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore, you can search for windwos forms recommend git ignore.

Close the solution,
Reopen solution,
Commit (push) .csproj, .sln files on the remote branch.

Comment: .gitignore was fine. I ended up re-adding the file from the filesystem and everything seem to have worked again. So the solutions seems to re-add the files, quite weird though as i would expect the files to be there automatically without re-adding them from the file system.

Comment: so, did you committed your .csproj files? if you don't do that you will face the same problem when you or someone will pull your branch.

Comment: the .csproject was already committed. When i added back the files it just worked without any issues, as if nothing had changed. VS didn't even complain that i had new files that have been added, but in the solution explorer there was [add] in front of all the new files that had been committed previously. So i just went ahead and added everything back again. So what worked was basically re-adding the files back again.

Comment: OK, still go on git (web) download the archive as zip from your specific branch, extract, and open it with visual studio see if it's working?

Comment: that did not work, i tried all solutions suggested. Its working now fine after i just re-added the files back when i opened the solution.

Comment: Well man, you need to commit .csproj files and .sln files, if someone else gets the code from git needs to work.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue then I found that in my .csproj file, my compile link is missing. For example, you can find `<Compile Include="Folder\YourCommittedFileLink.cs"/>`. If it doesn't exist, that's the reason why your Solution Explorer doesn't find it. Add it manually in your .csproj file and then Reload your Solution Explorer. Finally, commit this .csproj file also.

Comment: This is true for .NET Framework projects, where the files have to "opt-in" to being part of the project.  In .NET Core, it's the reverse, instead files have to "opt-out" of being part of the project. -- Long story short, make sure to commit your .csproj file changes, because they're important. 

Answer (score 0):

... Try the New Git user experience. In the “Tools” top level menu, select “Options…”. Under “Environment”, choose the “Preview Features” page. Check or uncheck the checkbox that says “New Git user experience”. This will add a new tool window, as well as functionality build around Git....

[original post on](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1141222/vs-2019-cannot-find-the-commit-code-function-after.html#)

Answer (score 0):

See the file extension of your files in gitignore, if they are there, remove it. then push again.