# After pulling from GIT files are shown in Windows File Explorer but files are excluded in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, model-view-controller

Excluded in Solution Explorer:

[image: Excluded in Solution Explorer]

Present in Windows Explorer
[image: Present in Windows Explorer]

Comment: Right-click in the solution explorer and "include in project"?

Comment: yeah thats a one way to do but i need other ways to make it included. is there any files that needs to be pushed.

Comment: Well, I guess you could *manually* edit the `.csproj` file to include them.  If you really want to.  But just right-clicking in the IDE seems considerably easier.

Comment: yeah i wanted to know if commiting and pushing the .csproj file will resolve this problem??

Comment: If that file includes that change, yes.  If it doesn't, no.  You really seem to be overcomplicating this.  If you want to include the files in the project, then include the files in the project.  What exactly isn't working here?

Comment: problem is i have to manually include the file thats have been changed.

Comment: You're going to have to be more descriptive than that.  For one thing, including files in a project and committing changes to source control are two completely different things.  Which one of these things is the actual problem here?  It's not clear at all how you're breaking this.

Comment: You are *not* commiting the individual files and folders, those are already commited. You are comitting only the .csproj file changes, which tells the visual studio whose files are part of the project.

Comment: ok can please tell me one thing, after pushing any new files from GIT, are those files meant to be manually included in Visual Studio??

Comment: @ProAayush: If those files weren't included in the project, or if they were on another workstation but that change to the project wasn't committed to source control, then yes.  Again, if you want to include files in the project, then you would have to include files in the project.  Somewhere someone on your team is breaking this concept.  Could be you, could be someone else.  We can't know, because you aren't describing the situation.  All you're doing is asking if you need to include files in the project if you want them included in the project.  The answer to that is yes.

Comment: @David you may consider adding the comment as an answer, so it could be voted / marked as an answer if ProAayush considers it correct

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39742959/visual-studio-not-showing-committed-files-in-solution-explorer

this is what my problem is

Comment: If someone added the folders on disk, and added them to the git staging area, committed, then pushed, and then you pulled, getting the folders on disk, but not included in the visual studio project, then go talk to that someone. It seems something was forgotten when the original folders were added. To be clear, when you pull a commit in git you should only have do a manual "include in project" operation it this wasn't done to begin with. There is nothing wrong with git or the git extension in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One file can be added to the GIT repo but not included to the Visual Studio project, that is your situation. You should:

1. Include the missing files in the Visual Studio project (or manually edit the `.csproj`, I dont recommend this, it is a pain in the ass)
2. Commit and Push the updated .csproj file to the GIT repo

At this point your Project and the GIT would be in sync.

3. Optional, higly recomended: Consider using a GIT plugin in the Visual Studio. If you are already using it, it did something wrong and did not keep the sync, should not have happened.