# How to enable Github "Commit" from Solution Explorer (builtin source control section integration)?

Tags: visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

VS 2019 (16.7.1)

I can commit from Team Explorer (VS Github Extension), I can commit from console, but the "old good" commit from Solution Explorer "right-click" menu is gone.

Here how it should look :

[image]

When in my case VS do not display the whole Source Control section (Undo, Commit, etc). It looks like VS built in funcitonality do not recognize GITHUB repository in this folder. How to enable this VS built in funcitonality?

Comment: Please refer to [this document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39742959/visual-studio-not-showing-committed-files-in-solution-explorer).

Comment: Thank you. As I feel there is something important and new for me, but I still can't understand how to use the information from document to enable "build in Commit menu item" in Solution Explorer (file by itself is shown as changed, just there are no commit item in "right click menu").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to enable Github “Commit” from Solution Explorer (builtin source
> control section integration)?

After I tested repeatedly, I find that this is an issue on the  `VS2019 16.7.1`, `16.7.2` and also the latest version `16.7.3`.

When I add a project into **Source Control**, then push it into GitHub repository, I cannot see the **Commit** menu item on the **Solution Explorer** either.

As this picture shows:

[image]

**However**, when I changed to use `VS2017` or `VS2019 16.6.x`, I can see the **Commit** menu on the **Solution Explorer** as expected.

[image]

**So I wonder this issue an issue on the 16.7.x version.**

**Also**, I have [reported the issue on our DC Forum and you can check it](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1181581/cannot-see-the-commit-menu-on-the-solution-explore.html). You can vote it or add any comment if I did not describe the issue in detail. And anyone who is interested in it will also vote it so that it will get more **Microsoft's** attention to resolve the issue as soon as possible.

=========================================================

**Besides**, this tip is a workaround and If it doesn't satisfy you, you can ignore it.

**As a workaround**, when you finish publishing your project on Github, please close your VS, and open the repository directly from the github repository of Team Explorer(**double-click** on the repository) and map it to the **solution explorer**.

It shows the whole structure of your repository. All files are displayed in the solution explorer. You can use commit there. Although its structure is too complicated to be optimized into the structure of the project,  **Commit** menu can be used.

[image]

If it does not satisfy you, you can ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently they are working on reintroducing it.
See attached link to vs2019
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1141222/vs-2019-cannot-find-the-commit-code-function-after.html

According to this discussion they are close to re-implementing the missing menu item.

Comment: Commit has been added back in under the git branch!